# dotnet pack command does not generate .nuget packages for tests and spec projects?

Tags: .net, nuget-package

We have a solution with mutiple projects that includes projects with unit and spec tests. When we run dotnet pack command on the solution the packages donot get generated for the unit and spec test projects. This is a good thing that it excludes test prjoects. Just wanted to understand how does not dotnet pack command exclude projects from being packaged.

On experimenting i noticed that when i added project dependency to xunit and xnit.runner.visualstudio on any project then dotnet pack doesn't generate packages for that project.

dotnet pack  C:\Projects\SysScore_Integration\SysScore\SysScore.sln   --output C:\Projects\LocalNuGet\  /p:PackageVersion=1.0.1.8

Answer (score 18):

Adding the property `<IsPackable>true</IsPackable>` to the .csproj file fixes this.

Apparently having a reference to xUnit is all that is required to make a project be considered a "test project" - even if the project contains no tests. This interferes with the situation where for example one is writing a reusable test framework which uses or extends the test framework attributes. I would expect `dotnet pack` to at least print a warning explaining why the command is being ignored, but whoever implemented this clearly did not agree.

Comment: I strongly disagree with the tone of your second paragraph - I would suggest that *most* developers workflows don't involve needing to create NuGet packages for tests - I think it's an entirely reasonable default.

Comment: @JonSkeet at least print a message saying why the command is being ignored? I'm creating a test framework that is meant to be used from numerous projects. In order to apply the xUnit attributes, it needs to reference the xUnit package. This is the only sense in which it is a "test project". It contains no test methods.

Comment: That's interesting - with nunit, if you've *only* got the NUnit dependency (rather than the test adapter etc) and don't explicitly set IsPackable to False, it *does* generate a NuGet package. And it definitely *used* to warn about unpackable projects. I wonder at what point it stopped warning...

Comment: (I would still say that this is a relatively rare situation - yes, it's annoying if you're in it, but it would also be annoying to create a package by default when 90% of projects depending on xunit or nunit *don't* need to be packed.)

Comment: (For anyone reading these comments later, please note that my first comment was with reference to the second paragraph of revision 1.)

Comment: This solved it, but to add to the discussion when I create a xunit testproject it sets <IsPackable>false</IsPackable> so (I assume the default is true) why would it use anything else to decide if it should not pack?

Comment: This just cost me a whole lot of time. Is this something that's being decided by xunit, or by VS/MSBuild/whatever upon seeing that the project references xunit?

Comment: This is dumb, something as fundamental as dotnet pack should not presume things just because of a reference. It doesn't matter if 1%, 10% or 100% of people repackage test tools in this way, the fact is it can't be presumed, so don't presume it.